# Regex check sentence for a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a basic chat app with node js and I'm trying to add commands to the chat.
Example: A user can add a friend with this command `/add name`

```
t = "/add Smith"
var c = t.match(/^\s*([/](?:\S+\d+|add|send))\s+\S+/i);
console.log(c[0])
// '/add Smith'
```

But I can't get third word:

```
t = "/send Smith 5000"
var c = t.match(/^\s*([/](?:\S+\d+|add|send))\s+\S+/i);
console.log(c)
// '/send Smith'
//third variable is missing
```

It's still giving first two word in `c[0]`, but I need third too. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Personally I tend to do things like this manually by splitting and examining the first word, then branching off to examine the following command specific options

Comment: Actually I was doing like that but I wanted to try regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\S+` will match 1 or more non spaces so it stops as soon as it finds a space after `Smith`. Use `.+` to match everything after `"send "`.

```
var c = t.match(/^\s*([/](?:\S+\d+|add|send))\s+.+/i);
//=> ["/send Smith 5000", "/send"]
```